# bootstrap jumbotron full width image

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a cover on all pages.. I am using jumbotron to have a full width image. but it leaves a space on right and left side. I added margin-left so the blank space on left was gone but the right one is still there. Also when I resize the browser there is a very large space on the right side.

```
<div id="cover-success" class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>Success Stories</h1>
                <h2>Here are some of the many resolved complaints.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS used:

```
#cover-success.jumbotron {
background-size: cover;
background-image: url('Images/cover-success-stories.jpg');
 position:absolute;
width:100%;
margin-top: -14px;
margin-left: -70px;
margin-right:-50px;
height: 270px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try for padding too

```
 #cover-success.jumbotron {
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url('Images/cover-success-stories.jpg');
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: 270px;
 }
```

Comment: I tried but then there is a blank space on left, the image moves a bit of more on right and i get an horizontal scrollbar which I dont want

Comment: Seems a image size ratio problem.. for the scroll bar add overflow:hidden; and try change the height

Comment: I did.. but no use.. facing the same issue.. Image has a good ratio. see this cover image: http://www.ichangemycity.com/bangalore/success-stories

Comment: Two suggestion .1- try without position absolute 2) try inspecting with firebugs for find the css element that is responsible for it ..and give me a feedback otherwise give me a live link for inspecting myself the live problem..